# How to map reduce the friends search in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a friend list (list of object ids), and a search query. I want to search *my friends* whose first name is starting *like the search query*. I can see I need to use map/reduce, but I don't think of how to do it.

```
class UserAccount(Document):
    first_name = StringField(max_length = 20)
    last_name = StringField(max_length = 20)
    user_name = StringField(max_length = 20)
    email = EmailField()
    password = StringField(max_length = 20)
    friends = ListField(ReferenceField('self'))


# List Of Friends IDs
friends = [ObjectId("5278a1821d41c80d7a3ed4ec"), ObjectId("5278a1821d41c80d7a3ed4fe"), 
ObjectId("5278a1821d41c80d7a3ed4aa"), ObjectId("5278a1821d41c80d7a3ed4bb")]    

# Assume a search query. 
search_query = 'some-name'

regex = re.compile('^' + re.escape(search_query))
users = UserAccount._get_collection()
result = users.find( 
{ 
    "_id" : friends[0], 
    "first_name" : regex                    
})
```

Any help or references are appreciated?

Comment: Could you provide example documents and expected output. It is not clear what you want and why you think about using m-r.

Comment: class UserAccount(Document):
 first_name = StringField(max_length = 20)
 last_name = StringField(max_length = 20)
 user_name = StringField(max_length = 20) 
 email = EmailField()
 password = StringField(max_length = 20)
 friends = ListField(ReferenceField('self'))

Comment: I want to let users search their friends... ( lets say they have 1000 friends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for map reduce - this should find all matching friends:

```
UserAccount.objects.filter(pk__in=friends, name=regex)
```

Comment: regex = re.compile('^' + re.escape('P'))
users = UserAccount._get_collection()
result = users.find(pk__in=friends, first_name=regex)

Correct me if i'm doing it wrong... This didn't work, it returned all the documents in the useraccount collection

Comment: did u mean "filter" instead of "find" cuz its worked